# How to upgrade to fontawesome5 pro version for expo react native project

Tags: react-native, expo, font-awesome

I am using free version of fontawesome 5 from @expo/vector-icons. How can I include(use) my downloaded font awesome pro icons in expo project. Shall I create custom fonts using  https://docs.expo.io/guides/icons/#createiconset or Is there any way to upgrade to fontawesome pro version?

Answer (score 1):

I am running into the same issue. There is an open issue regarding this on github. It seems that pro icons are not officially supported.

https://github.com/expo/vector-icons/issues/91

Comment: It would be also helpful to post the proposed solutions from the issues post

Comment: This is not an answer, if you want to address the question by stating that you have the same issue, leave a comment.